# How Can I get Latest 5 Commentors user information By Laravel Relational Eloquent eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm in a situation where I need to display the last 5 unique commenters information at the top of the comment list as follows screenshot.

[comment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlt1.png)

To do this. I did as follows:
Post Model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function commenter_avatars(){

    return $this->comments()->distinct('user_id')
        ->select('id','post_id','user_id','parent_id')
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with('user')->limit(5);
}
```

My Controller method as follows

```
public function index() {

    $feeds = auth()->user()
        ->posts()
        ->with(['user:id,first_name,last_name,username,avatar', 'media', 'commenter_avatars'])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    return PostResource::collection($feeds);
}
```

I tried to use groupBy and Distinct.. But did't work as expected.

Did I miss something? or Have there any more best way to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Noted: I am using latest Laravel (8.48ˆ)

Comment: Please include code and not links and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using eloquent-eager-limit

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your joining of post, user and comments table. But i guess, you can do something similar to following.

At first get latest 5 unique user id of one post:

```
$userIds = Comments::where("post_id", $post_id)->distinct("user_id")->orderBy("id")
                    ->limit(5)->pluck('user_id');
```

Then, fetch those user information

```
$users = Users::whereIn("id", $userIds )->get();
```

Then, you can return those users

**UPDATE**

You may use `map()` to fetch and reorder output. Following is an idea for you:

In Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
$skipNumber = $request->input("skip"); // this is need for offsetting purpose
$userIds = [];

$feeds = Posts::with("comments")->where("comments.user_id", Auth::id())
                ->skip($skipNumber)->take(10)->orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')
                 ->map(function ($item) use($userIds){
                    $users = [];
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach($item["comments"] as $comment) {
                        if(!in_array($comment["user_id"], $userIds) && $count < 5){
                           $count++;
                           $userIds.push($comment["user_id"])
                           $user = User::where("id", $comment["user_id"])->first();
                           $users.push($user);
                        }
                        if($count == 5) break;
                    }
                    $data = [
                             "post" => $item,
                             "latest_users" => $users
                            ];
                    return $data;
                    
                  })->get();

 return PostResource::collection($feeds);
```

}

My code syntax may be slightly wrong. Hopefully you will get the idea.

Comment: thanks for replying @nazem

As you can see my code, I am doing paginate 10 records per request. If I apply your solution, then for each requests, It will generate extra 20 queries. After then I have to remap data for each post.  

So, I think, It will effect on query performnace. and It is a N+1 query problem

Comment: understood. sorry couldnt come up with a solution which solve your problem in query side. It becomes so complex. But I have a solution in my mind, which you may apply either in laravel controller or in frontside after fetching data. Step 1) firstly, fetch all posts with comments of a user with commentators info, in desc order of comment_id. Step 2) Then, find the unique/distinct user_id from the commentators, and push those info in an array. If you do it in same controller you just have to pass another data from controller. Or you can do this finding in front side.

Comment: Thank you again for quick response! Your said solution is good. I belive that it will works.. but there have a memory issue. imagine, if each post have hundreds of comments for each posts (For 10 posts => 1000 comments) then we losts lots of server memory. We cannot gurantee that there will be have 1000+ comments in the future.. :-(

Comment: @AnwarHossen I have updated a code sample. The syntax might be slightly wrong. But that is an idea. Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: Sorry for too much late.. 
I tried your solution.. But there have query performance issue again.. As I said, for each post having 100+ comments. so, I cannot load all comments at a time..

As I have research on Laravel.. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835  It is actually a limitaion of eloquent.. But I solved this problem using a package.. 
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit 
Thank you so much for your help..